# emulateapj options not changing anything

Tags: typography, package-options, options

simple question: how do you change an option with emulateapj?

I'm using `\documentclass[12pt, apj]{emulateapj}` but it appears to have no effect  and comes up with these messages:

```
[Compiling C:\Users\User\Documents\Project work\Latex Report\Main\master.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Invoking texify... done.

No errors. Warnings:

C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\revtex\revtex4-1.cls: Class revtex4-1 Warning: No Society specified, using default society aps.
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\revtex\revtex4-1.cls: Class revtex4-1 Warning: No journal specified, using default pra.
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\revtex\revtex4-1.cls: Class revtex4-1 Warning: No type size specified, using default 10.
C:/Users/User/Documents/Project work/Latex Report/Main/master.tex: LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):    [fontsize=5mm].
C:/Users/User/Documents/Project work/Latex Report/Main/master.tex: Class revtex4-1 Warning: Assuming \noaffiliation for authors.
C:\Users\User\Documents\Project work\Latex Report\Main\master.bbl:3: LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.
```

My main needs are to change the font size and typeset (12pt and apj), but it looks like nothing changes. It stays at 10pt and preprint/something else!
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [`emulateapj`](http://ctan.org/pkg/emulateapj) doesn't provide a `12pt` document class option. However, it loads [`revtex4-1`](http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) if it exists with a number of options. Perhaps add `\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{revtex4-1}` before `\documentclass[apj]{emulateapj}`.

Comment: Why do you want to use that class?

Comment: I want to get rid of the 'DRAFT VERSION' as shown here https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/emulateapj/. Mine still comes up with it